# How to run a build process from Java program?

Tags: java, swing, process, build-process

I'm writing an IDE for LaTeX. To build my a LaTeX file, I created another process within my GUI, so if the user hit the button, it will run:

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

This is the code in Java:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pdflatex.exe", currentFileName);
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
}
```

When I run the above command from command line (cmd), it worked fine and a pdf file was created. However, running it from my Java program always give me an error log. It generated two other files: `file.log` and `file.aux` but the pdf was hung. Could anyone give me a hint where I miss? I really couldn't see anything wrong with this approach.

```
**Tex error log**

**hello.tex
(C:\Users\chan\git\Comp585\JavaTextEditor\hello.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen111
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen112
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 211.
\uproot@=\count91
\leftroot@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 307.
\classnum@=\count93
\DOTSCASE@=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 382.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen113
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568.
\macc@depth=\count95
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count97
\dspbrk@lvl=\count98
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count99
\column@=\count100
\maxfields@=\count101
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen114
\alignsep@=\dimen115
\tagshift@=\dimen116
\tagwidth@=\dimen117
\totwidth@=\dimen118
\lineht@=\dimen119
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2666.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2667.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 96.
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\classes\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2004/08/06 v2.20
\thm@style=\toks21
\thm@bodyfont=\toks22
\thm@headfont=\toks23
\thm@notefont=\toks24
\thm@headpunct=\toks25
\thm@preskip=\skip46
\thm@postskip=\skip47
\thm@headsep=\skip48
\dth@everypar=\toks26
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2009/06/22 v3.00
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\polynomial\polynomial.sty
Package: polynomial 
\shpol@numcoeff=\count102
\shpol@coeffnum=\count103
\shpol@exponent=\count104
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\layouts\layouts.sty
Package: layouts 2009/09/02 v2.6d graphical depiction of document elements
\l@ylen=\skip49
\layoutsbox=\box28
\l@youtunitlength=\skip50
\l@youtlinethick=\skip51
\l@youtlinethickii=\skip52
\l@ysetupparskip=\skip53
\l@ysetupbaselineskip=\skip54
\l@yonem=\skip55
\l@yonex=\skip56
\l@ylmarg=\skip57
\l@yrmarg=\skip58
\l@yitmindent=\skip59
\l@ylblwidth=\skip60
\l@ylblsep=\skip61
\l@ylparindent=\skip62
\l@ytsep=\skip63
\l@ypskip=\skip64
\l@yptsep=\skip65
\l@ypsep=\skip66
\l@yitmsep=\skip67
\l@ytok=\toks27
\l@youtpw=\count105
\l@youtph=\count106
\l@youthpi=\count107
\l@youthpii=\count108
\l@youthpiii=\count109
\l@youthpiv=\count110
\l@youthpv=\count111
\l@youthpvi=\count112
\l@youthpvii=\count113
\l@youtparskip=\count114
\l@youtvpi=\count115
\l@youtvpii=\count116
\l@youtvpiii=\count117
\l@youtvpiv=\count118
\l@youtvpv=\count119
\l@youtvpvi=\count120
\l@youtvpvii=\count121
\l@youthdo=\count122
\l@youthdi=\count123
\l@youthdii=\count124
\l@youthdiii=\count125
\l@youthdiv=\count126
\l@youthdv=\count127
\l@youthdvi=\count128
\l@youthdvii=\count129
\l@youtvdo=\count130
\l@youtvdi=\count131
\l@youtvdii=\count132
\l@youtvdiii=\count133
\l@youtvdiv=\count134
\l@youtvdv=\count135
\l@youtvdvi=\count136
\l@youtvdvii=\count137
\l@youtvdviii=\count138
\l@youtxci=\count139
\l@youtxcii=\count140
\l@youtxciii=\count141
\l@youtxciv=\count142
\l@youtxcv=\count143
\l@youtxcvi=\count144
\l@youtyci=\count145
\l@youtycii=\count146
\l@youtyciii=\count147
\l@youtyciv=\count148
\l@youtycv=\count149
\l@youtycvi=\count150
\l@youtycvii=\count151
\l@youtycviii=\count152
\l@youtxco=\count153
\l@youtyco=\count154
\l@ytempdima=\skip68
\stockwidth=\skip69
\stockheight=\skip70
\trimedge=\skip71
\trimtop=\skip72
\uppermargin=\skip73
\spinemargin=\skip74
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty"
Package: enumerate 1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks28
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\mdwtools\syntax.sty
Package: syntax 1996/05/17 1.07 Syntax typesetting (MDW)
\grammarparsep=\skip75
\grammarindent=\dimen120
\sdstartspace=\skip76
\sdendspace=\skip77
\sdmidskip=\skip78
\sdtokskip=\skip79
\sdfinalskip=\skip80
\sdrulewidth=\dimen121
\sdcirclediam=\dimen122
\sdindent=\dimen123
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\was\gensymb.sty
Package: gensymb 2003/07/02 v1.0 (WaS)
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\enumitem\enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2011/09/05 v3.5.1 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip81
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen124
\enit@toks=\toks29
\enit@inbox=\box29
\enitdp@description=\count155
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\cancel\cancel.sty
Package: cancel 2000/03/12 v2.1 Cancel math terms
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count156
\calc@Bcount=\count157
\calc@Adimen=\dimen125
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen126
\calc@Askip=\skip82
\calc@Bskip=\skip83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count158
\calc@Cskip=\skip84
)
(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count159
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(C:\Users\chan\git\Comp585\JavaTextEditor\hello.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: letterpaper
* layout: 
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


Package layouts Warning: Layout scale set to 0.5 on input line 19.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 19.
Package gensymb Info: Faking symbols for \degree and \celsius on input line 19.


Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 19.
Package gensymb Info: Using \Omega for \ohm on input line 19.

Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

(C:\Users\chan\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count160
\scratchdimen=\dimen127
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count161
\nofMParguments=\count162
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count163
\MPscratchDim=\dimen128
\MPnumerator=\count164
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count165
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 23.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 23.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
) [1

{C:/Users/chan/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\chan\git\Comp585\JavaTextEditor\hello.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3796 strings out of 494045
 49794 string characters out of 3145972
 132506 words of memory out of 3000000
 7060 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5339 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 715 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,5n,35p,222b,117s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb): fflush() failed (Invalid argument)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to gobble your streams so as not to run out of buffer space. Do you have any error messages or error text in files that we can see? This article is a little dated, but the message it contains is important and still relevant even if the code is a little out of date: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: Oh, and it is *very* important that you start your process in a background thread, and it is ***extremely*** important that you don't ignore exceptions as it appears you are doing: `catch (IOException e1) { }`. It's as if you were trying to learn to drive a car with blindfolds on.

Comment: In fact, I tried to run that process in another thread, but it did the same thing, so I moved it back into my GUI code. See my edit for the `tex` error file. Thanks for the references by the way.

Comment: What results if you print out the IOException's stack trace in your catch block?

Comment: There were no `IOException` was thrown.

Comment: Have you tried this on a very simple and proven error-free file? Have you tried profiling things to see if you run out of memory or other resources?

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know those things that you have mentioned. I've started to learn Swing for couple weeks. I know Java, but at a very basic level.

Comment: When you run this from the command line, does it generate some lines on the command line? If so, again consider creating a stream gobbler as per the article in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it out, there was a problem with the `LaTeX` package. In other words, if I delete some of the packages, it worked fine. However, I still don't understand why running from the command line works, but the process failed.

Comment: I can't help with the specifics here as I don't have your LaTex anything, just with the generalities. Again, if you get a chance, please read the article linked to above. The only thing out of date in it (that I know of) is some operating system-specific code, but that's easily fixed.

Comment: I will definitely read those articles. I will handle all those exceptions, put them into their right thread and write robust code. At this moment, I've just tried to learn Swing API, Java API... so that I know what I can do with them. Many thanks for your help and advice.